# Sampling from a Convolutional Restricted Boltzmann Machine's Visible Gaussian Real-valued Units

Tags: normal-distribution, neural-networks, sampling, convolution, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am trying to confirm whether or not I am understanding the process described in the title.

I am implementing a CRMB (with Real Valued Gaussian Visible units and Binary hidden units) as outlined in [Lee et al (2009b)](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3674-unsupervised-feature-learning-for-audio-classification-using-convolutional-deep-belief-networks.pdf), explained deeper in [Lee et al (2009a)](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ergrosse/icml09-cdbn.pdf).

**I understand sampling at the hidden layer (Binary Units) to involve:**

- For each group of hidden units, for each hidden unit find the probability of it being "on", given the input $v$:

$$P(h_j^k = 1|v) = sigmoid \big((\tilde{W}^k *_v v)_j + b_k\big)$$

where $*_v$ is the "valid" convolution - valid convolution of the transpose of group $k$'s weight matrix with the input.

- Now to get the final Sample, for each hidden unit, you sample once from a Binomial Distribution with std dev = 1 and mean = the hidden unit's probability of being "on" - if this sampled value < the probability of the unit being "on", set the value of the hidden unit = 1.

This creates the "Sampled" value of the hidden layers - which will then be used as the starting point in the chain of Gibbs sampling in the Contrastive Divergence algorithm.

**Now sampling at the visible layer (Gaussian Real units)**

The papers listed define the probability of each visible unit being "on", given a group of Hidden Unit binary vectors:

$$P(v_i|\mathbf{h}) = Normal \Big(\sum_k (W^k *_f h^k)_i + c, 1\Big)$$

where $*_f$ is the "full" convolution - the "full" convolution of group $k$'s weight matrix with the $k$th group of hidden unit values.

They do not elaborate on the function:

$$Normal(x,y)$$

Does this mean to sample the value from a normal distribution with mean = $x$ and std dev = $y$?

Does this also mean then that the probability of a visible unit being on IS the sample of that visible unit?

I've added a Python function below to hopefully explain how I believe this sampling is defined to work in a less ambiguous way:

```py
def sample_v_given_h(self, hidden_groups):
    pre_sampled = np.zeros(self.visible_layer_shape)
    for group in range(1, self.numBases):
        #scipy.signal.convolve2d(matX, matY, mode)
        pre_sampled += convolve2d(hidden_groups[group], self.weight_groups[group], mode='full')

    #shared visible bias
    pre_sampled += self.visible_bias

    #rng is numpy.random.RandomState.normal(loc, scale, size)
    #It samples from normal distribution
    #loc is the mean
    #scale is the std deviation
    sampled = self.rng.normal(loc=pre_sampled, scale=1, size=self.visible_layer_shape)

    #returning both pre-sampled and sampled values respectively for now
    return [pre_sampled, sampled]
```

Am I understanding this all correctly? Are my uses of the mean correct in both the binary and Gaussian cases?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, looks like to got them correct.

Your first equation gives the probability that a hidden unit should be turned on, i.e. a number between (0 , 1). You then use that probability to obtain a sample, and then as you correctly say, use that sample as the beginning point for Gibbs sampling. An easy way to obtain a sample using the binary probabilities:

```
bin_sample = probs > np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=[shape of probs])
```

The method you mention using a Bernoulli distribution is equivalent.

Your second equation specifies the probability distribution that a real valued Gaussian Unit should take values from. To obtain a sample here, use the calculated probability for each hidden unit as the mean along with a standard deviation of 1, and draw from a normal distribution.

```
gaus_sample = np.random.normal(loc=probs, scale=1, size=[shape of probs])
```

Look at 'END OF POSITIVE PHASE'  [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/code/rbmhidlinear.m) for an example from Geoffrey Hinton.